# How to update a variable when target is called?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a variable that should not be evaluated prior to calling a phony target because it will have an empty value, for example:

```
VAR = /home/directory/file

.PHONY: target
target: 
  $(mkdir -p /home/directory)
  $(touch /home/directory/file)
```

Comment: Err, this makefile does nothing: you don't want to use `$(mkdir -p /home/directory)`, that tries to expand a make variable named, literally, `mkdir -p /home/directory` which doesn't exist so it expands to the empty string and is ignored.  You just want to write shell commands directly, not include them in `$(...)`.

Comment: I think this is an XY problem.  I think what you're trying to do is probably not a great way of doing things, but you didn't give us enough detail about your actual goals to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) right after the `target:`:

```
target:
    $(eval VAR = /home/directory/file)
```

and remove the first line (`VAR = ...`).